# Storing API data into UserDefaults and printing to a list

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In my app, users scan a barcode and the information about the product is fetched from an API.

I want to create a history section, where users can view the last 10 products.

The result from the API data is stored in a Result type, which for it to be able to be shown in a list, has to be identifiable.

Result is a custom data type that I'm using to store the details of the products from the API call in.

**Result**

```
struct Result: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var description: String?
    var brand: String?
    var ingredients: String?
    var image: String?
    var upc_code: String?
    var return_message: String?
    var return_code: String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case description, brand, ingredients, image, upc_code, return_message, return_code
    }
}
```

This data types store the array of Result which I'll display as a list

**History**

```
struct History: Codable {
    var results: [Result]
}
```

Here's the API call:

```
func loadData(url: String, completion: @escaping (Error?, Result?) -> Void ) {
    if let url = URL(string: url) {
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {return}
            
            do {
                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                let encoder = JSONEncoder()
                if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(data) {
                    var sizeCheck = defaults.object(forKey:"productHistory") as? [Data] ?? [Data]()
                    if (sizeCheck.count == 10) { //Check if there's more than 10 products already on the history list
                        sizeCheck.removeLast()
                    }
                    sizeCheck.append(encoded) //Add new product to list
                    defaults.set(sizeCheck, forKey: "productHistory") //Add new list to userDefaults
                }
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let result: Result = try decoder.decode(Result.self, from: data)
                completion(nil, result) //Used elsewhere to display the scanned product after it's been added to the history list
            }
            catch let e {
                print(e)
                completion(e, nil)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

This is my view that shows the last 10 products in a list when a button is pressed.

The last 10 products should be stored in UserDefaults with the key `productHistory`. This is done in the API call LoadData()

```
struct historyView: View {
    @Binding var showingHistory: Bool
    @State private var results = [Result]()
    
    var body: some View {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let products = defaults.object(forKey: "productHistory") as? Data {
            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(History.self, from: products) {
                self.results = decodedResponse.results
            }
        }
        return List(self.results, id: \.id) { item in
            Text(item.description!)
        }
    }
}
```

To my understanding, the issue is that UserDefaults can't store JSON data. So when the API data is fetched, I store the data as it is, into userdefualts. Then decode it when I need it, like storing it in history or displaying it.

Currently I'm getting a blank list and the if statement below isn't passing.

```
if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(History.self, from: products) {
```

Here's the JSON data from the API if I paste the URL into the browser:

[image]

EDIT

Here's my APICall():

```
func callAPI() -> String {
        if (scannedCode.barcode == "") {
            return "noneScanned"
        }
        else {
            let hashedValue = scannedCode.barcode.hashedValue("API ID")
            //print(hashedValue!)
            loadData(url: "URL") { error, result  in
                if let err = error {
                    self.APIresult = err.localizedDescription
                    print(APIresult)
                    //output error
                }
                else if (result?.ingredients == nil) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.APIresult = "noIngredients"
                    }
                }
                else if (result?.description == nil) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.APIresult = "noDescription"
                    }
                }
                else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.APIresult = "success"
                    }                    
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    product.result = result!
//updates view that show's the scanned product, as it's @Published
                }
            }
            return APIresult
        }
    }
```

In this section, I want to find what data I have about the product and process it accordingly. Therefore with the solution above, I return a different value depending on if it's got a image or a description etc...

With vadian solution, I've changed it to this:

```
          loadData(url: "URL") { result  in
                switch result {
                case .success(product):
                    print("success")
                case .failure(error):
                    print("failure")
                }
            }
```

Comment: Don't use `try?`. Use `do-try-catch` instead and print the error.

Comment: Your approach is wrong. You are mixing up the structs and `Data` instances. For example `sizeCheck` is `Data`, `sizeCheck.count` are the bytes, not the number of `Result` instances. And you are decoding once `Result` and once `History` which cannot work. And it's unclear whether you are going to save `History` or an array of `Result` into `UserDefaults`. Sorry your design is a mess. And – as pawello2222 – already mentioned **never ever** ignore errors with `try?` in a `Codable` context. By the way `Result` is a built-in generic type. You should rename the struct.

Comment: @vadian I've found that `if let products = defaults.object(forKey: "productHistory") as? Data` isn't passing, I'm trying to print an error for it. Is it possible for my to achieve what I want using userdefaults?

Comment: The main issue is `try? encoder.encode(data)`. You are encoding `Data` rather than an instance of `History` or `Result`. And once again `sizeCheck` is not an array of products, it"s `Data`. `removeLast` removes the last byte which is `UInt8`, not the last product.

Comment: @vadian does data need to be encoded at all? Could it be converted to Result then stored in UserDefualts?

Comment: Yes, of course, but it’s still unclear what (exactly) you are going to accomplish and what JSON you get from the API

Comment: @vadian I've added a screenshot of the data from the API. I want to store the last 10 products that have been scanned into list. I decided to use UserDefualts as it'll remember the data. So I want to store each product into an array that I can print out to a list.

Comment: I'd recommend you move saving the data in `UserDefaults` to a separate function e.g. `func cache(_ result: Result)`. So move all the encoding stuff in your `loadData` to this function. Then once you have your result after `let result = try decoder.decode(Result.self, from: data)`, you'll then call `cache(result)` followed by `completion(nil, result)`. After that, it will be easier to fix your caching logic, which is where the main problem is

Comment: Also, as mentioned `Result` is a built-in generic type, that's quite handy when dealing with API calls. So it would be better to name your model something else e.g. `Recipe` or `Product`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you are mixing up `Data` and `Result`

First of all drop `History` and rename `Result` as `Product`. We are going to save an array of `Product` to `UserDefaults`

```
struct Product: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var description: String?
    var image: String?
    var upc_code: String?
    var return_message: String?
    var return_code: String?
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case description, image, upc_code, return_message, return_code
    }
}
```

In `loadData` use the generic `Result` type as closure parameter. After receiving the data decode it to a `Product` instance, then load the saved array, remove the first(!) item (if necessary) append the new item, save the array back and call completion with the new `Product`. All potential errors are passed in the `failure` case.

```
func loadData(url: String, completion: @escaping (Result<Product,Error>) -> Void ) {
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error { completion(.failure(error));  return }
        
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let product = try decoder.decode(Product.self, from: data!)
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            var history = [Product]()
            if let readData = defaults.data(forKey:"productHistory") {
                do {
                    history = try decoder.decode([Product].self, from: readData)
                    if history.count == 10 { history.removeFirst() }
                } catch { print(error) }
            }
            history.append(product)
            let saveData = try JSONEncoder().encode(history)
            defaults.set(saveData, forKey: "productHistory")
            completion(.success(product))
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

and call it

```
loadData(url: "URL") { result  in
    switch result {
    case .success(let product):
       if product.ingredients == nil {
           self.APIresult = "noIngredients"
       } else if product.description == nil {
           self.APIresult = "noDescription"
       } else {
           self.APIresult = "success"                  
       }
       product.result = product           

    case .failure(let error):
       self.APIresult = error.localizedDescription
       print(APIresult)
    }
}
```

In `HistoryView` (please name structs with starting uppercase letter) get the data from `UserDefaults` and decode the `Product` array.

```
struct HistoryView: View {
    @Binding var showingHistory: Bool
    @State private var results = [Product]()
    
    var body: some View {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let historyData = defaults.data(forKey: "productHistory") {
            do {
                self.results = try JSONDecoder().decode([Product].self, from: historyData)
            } catch { print(error) }
        }
        return List(self.results, id: \.id) { item in
            Text(item.description ?? "n/a")
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Be aware that the UUID is not being encoded and saved.

And please use more descriptive variable names.

Comment: that's brilliant, thank you. I've implemented your solution, but I'm wondering how I deal with the returns of LoadData(). I've updated my post of what callAPI() was and how I've changed it to suit your solution. However, I'm currently getting a loop of "success"

Comment: See the edit. The return value of `callAPI` is pointless because `loadData` is asynchronous